# How can I do this with UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want the effect like this:

[image][image]

When I scroll the word from "image1" to "image2" then the background also change, I just don't know how to set the word detection(the line).

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *myscrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    myscrollView.delegate = self;
    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(100, 150);
    [myscrollView setContentOffset:position animated:YES];
 }
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *) scrollView{
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
}
```

Comment: no images are shown

Comment: Hi, and welcome! You've added the tag for Swift (the newer iOS language), but the code you've given is in Objective-C (the old iOS language). Which development language are you looking for solutions in?

Comment: sorry I posted Objective-C that is the code I am trying to fix it.
but it seems can't work. I am finding the new code with UIScroll in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, and inside call `yourScrollView.contentOffset` to check how much you scrolled; then make the necessary changes.

Another way, is by checking if the frame of the scrollView intersects the frame of the label, using `CGRect`'s [`intersects`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454747-cgrectintersectsrect?language=objc) function inside of `scrollViewDidScroll`. This might be the easier one.

Check the documentation for [`scrollViewDidScroll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc) if you need more info.

Comment: I am using a UITextView that can scroll. I mean when I scroll in ''UITextView'', I can do that.